# Why are the boarders showing differently on a table?

Tags: html, css, border, border-collapse

Why are the boarders showing differently on a table?

Originally I had `<div class="tr">` and things like that because the main body of my site is in `flex` inside `@media screen`. This specific portion of my site is on `@media print`

Here is my code for it:

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Drug Names</th>
        <th>Prescriber</th>
        <th>Dose/Pill</th>
        <th>Frequency</th>
        <th>Rx Number</th>
        <th>Pharmacy</th>
        <th class="tinyBoxes">M</th>
        <th class="tinyBoxes">T</th>
        <th class="tinyBoxes">W</th>
        <th class="tinyBoxes">T</th>
        <th class="tinyBoxes">F</th>
        <th class="tinyBoxes">S</th>
        <th class="tinyBoxes">S</th>
        <th>Remaining
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

tr {
    display: table-row;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
    display: table-cell;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

td {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.tinyBoxes {
    width: 0.5cm;
    height: 0.5cm;
    display: table-cell;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

An Image of what it's displaying on Chrome (most current version): [Image of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdKd5.jpg)

Any ideas why the borders are being different?

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

I did a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fj1wn34x/) and it seems to work just fine on there. I guess it's a browser thing...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

> border: 1px solid black;

from 'table', 'tr' tags and '.tinyBoxes' class in your CSS code, and just write it in the 'th' tag, then it's OK.